# Import missing despite already downloaded Python

Tags: python-3.x, import, missing-data

I realize this is a beginner question, I'm just starting out. I'm trying to put real time currency changes for a simple currency converter app.
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntx2n.png)

I download forex_python.converter and it marks it as missing. Is it going to the wrong file? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed on your windows ?

Comment: -2     : Launch the latest Python 2.x version
-3     : Launch the latest Python 3.x version
-X.Y   : Launch the specified Python version

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple python versions installed on your machine. When you call `pip3 install forex-python` in your screenshot, you see that it is installing in a location `C:\python311\lib\site-packages`. But in your Interactive Development Environment (IDE) you are referencing a different python version "3.10.11". Change your python interpreter in your IDE environment settings to point to the correct location and it will register the library correctly. See the Microsoft Documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) for how to configure python environments in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: To further add on, a good practice is to use a virtual environment or docker container to containerise your application to maintain consistency and avoid such conflicts.